# Modifying and Displaying Student Details

Tags: java

I'm making a Java program that manages student details and would like some help in modifying and displaying a student detail.

Here's a code I did for Searching a Student and have thought about recycling the code to Modify and Display a Student, however, I'm stuck.

```
 public static void searchStudent(){
    try{
        BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        System.out.println("--- Searching for a Student ---");
        System.out.print("Enter Student Number, Last Name or First Name: ");
        String option = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Searching for '" + option + "' in the Student File");
        System.out.print("\n");

        while((line = readFile.readLine()) != null){
            int indexFile = line.indexOf(option);

            if(indexFile > -1){
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
        readFile.close();
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("Error Searching for a Student !!!");
    }
}
```

Here's my code for Displaying a Student, any tips on how I can work around it? Thanks in advance

```
public static void displayStudent(){
    try{
        BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        System.out.println("--- Displaying Student Details ---");
        System.out.print("Enter Student Number: ");
        String option = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Searching for Student '" + option + "' in the Student File");
        System.out.print("\n");

        while((line = readFile.readLine()) != null){
            int indexFile = line.indexOf(option);

            if(indexFile > -1){
                System.out.println("Student Number: " + myArray.get(line)[0]);
                System.out.println("Last Name: " + myArray.get(line)[1]);
                System.out.println("First Name: " + myArray.get(line)[2]);
                System.out.println("Email Address: " + myArray.get(line)[3]);
                System.out.println("Mobile Number: " + myArray.get(line)[4]);
            }
        }
        readFile.close();
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("Error Displaying a Student !!!");
    }
}
```

ArrayList myArray is populated by:

```
for(int x = 0; x < myArray.size(); x++){
            bw.write(myArray.get(x)[0] + ";");
            bw.write(myArray.get(x)[1] + ";");
            bw.write(myArray.get(x)[2] + ";");
            bw.write(myArray.get(x)[3] + ";");
            bw.write(myArray.get(x)[4] + ";");

            bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
```

Comment: any error/exception etc? What's your question?

Comment: Error: method ArrayList.get(int) is not applicable (actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)

Comment: How do you populate myArray i.e. aray list? Share all relevant code please.

Comment: static ArrayList<String[]> myArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();

Comment: I populate a line through BufferedWriter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
myArray.get(line)[0]
```

Use:

```
myArray.get(indexFile)[0]
```

So here you are accessing list element by index and then once you get the element, you try to access student name etc from list.

I would suggest, you use Student Object and make number, name etc as field of Student object rather than using Array.

Comment: Oh wow, Java really is complicated and one wrong move, it could ruin your whole program. I never realized I needed to use the "indexFile" instead of "line" as it was already connected.. Thanks SMA.

Comment: I have never used the tick button as I'm rarely in stackoverflow, I'll do so to support you! Thanks again!